# Deleted rows in HTML table stay at ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I just started learning javascript 3 months ago and started learning react.js 2 days ago. I created a simple TODO app, it does the right output but I didn't expect it. Can someone please explain to me why when I delete a row it will be deleted in DOM but not in React DOM. I will attach gist for the code, you will notice that I don't try to delete the task/record on data array so on the next render I expect deleted task will appear, but they don't.[image][image]
[image]

https://gist.github.com/cauldyclark15/1368bd6a1b444e7ebf90aea8ca55f0f6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of virtual dom concept. React uses diffing algorithm to see the difference between actual dom and dom stored in their object, so as to smartly re-render dom nodes.

[image]

Comment: thank you fella, I've read this in React's official documentation but maybe I was so amaze to really experience it, LOL. So the only option now is to believe it and use it.